# swi Prolog - find combined salaries for children in family structure

Tags: prolog

```
% family one

family(
   person(pat,marx,date(10,march,1944),unemployed),
    person(charlotte,marx,date(11,february,1946),unemployed),
[
    person(aine,marx,date(17,april,1985),unemployed),
    person(louis,marx,date(25,june,1980),works(harriott,32000)),
    person(pearl,marx,date(10,june,1981),unemployed),
    person(pat_jr,marx,date(11,march,1983),works(world_of_food,50000)),
    person(ricky,marx,date(18,february,1987),unemployed)
]
 ).


% family two

family(
    person(fred,chomsky,date(3,october,1955),works(bean_counters,100000)),
person(sarah,chomsky,date(19,october,1961),works(supercomms, 60000)),
[   person(amos,chomsky,date(1,july,1984),works(sell_cell, 80000))
]
).
```

i am trying to find the first name and surname of the mother who's children have a combined income less than 100,000.  I also want to bring back the combined income of the children's salaries.

so far i have this:

```
test(name, surname, CombinedIncome) :- 
   family(_,person(name,surname,_,_),Children),
   total_Income([],0]
   total_Income(family(_,_,_,works(_,salary))|Children],Income]
   CombinedIncome <100000
```

I'm a bit lost on how to finish accessing the list and getting the combined income and then testing that against the value of 100000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** extended the program with `predicates children_earning_over_40k/1` and `unemployed_fathers/1` upon request in comment.

```
% family one
family(
    person(pat,marx,date(10,march,1944),unemployed),
    person(charlotte,marx,date(11,february,1946),unemployed),
    [
        person(aine,marx,date(17,april,1985),unemployed),
        person(louis,marx,date(25,june,1980),works(harriott,32000)),
        person(pearl,marx,date(10,june,1981),unemployed),
        person(pat_jr,marx,date(11,march,1983),works(world_of_food,50000)),
        person(ricky,marx,date(18,february,1987),unemployed)
    ]
).

% family two
family(
        person(fred,chomsky,date(3,october,1955),works(bean_counters,100000)),
        person(sarah,chomsky,date(19,october,1961),works(supercomms, 60000)),
        [   person(amos,chomsky,date(1,july,1984),works(sell_cell, 80000))
        ]
    ).

total_income([], 0).

total_income([person(_,_,_,Work)|R], Total):-
    income(Work, Income),
    total_income(R, RestIncome),
    Total is Income + RestIncome.

income(unemployed, 0).
income(works(_, Income), Income).



mother_with_children_less_than_10k(Name, SurName, CombinedIncome):-
    family(_, person(Name, SurName, _, _), Children),
    total_income(Children, CombinedIncome),
    CombinedIncome > 100000.


children_earning_over_40k(ChildrenOver40k):-
    findall(X ,family(_,_,X), Res),
    flatten(Res, AllChildren),
    children_earning_over_40k(AllChildren, ChildrenOver40k).


children_earning_over_40k([person(Name, _, _, works(_, Salary))|R], [Name|Children1]):-
    Salary > 40000,
    children_earning_over_40k(R, Children1).

children_earning_over_40k([person(_, _, _, unemployed)|R], Children):-
    children_earning_over_40k(R, Children).

children_earning_over_40k([person(_, _, _, works(_, Salary))|R], Children):-
    Salary =< 40000,
    children_earning_over_40k(R, Children).

children_earning_over_40k([], []).

unemployed_fathers(Fathers):-
    findall(X ,family(X,_,_), Fathers1),
    unemployed_fathers(Fathers1, Fathers).

unemployed_fathers([person(Name, _, _, unemployed)|R], [Name | Fathers1]):-
    unemployed_fathers(R, Fathers1).


unemployed_fathers([person(_, _, _, works(_,_))|R], Fathers):-
    unemployed_fathers(R, Fathers).

unemployed_fathers([], []).
```

Test run for `mother_with_children_less_than_10k`:

```
?- mother_with_children_less_than_10k(Name, SurName, CombinedIncome).
Name = charlotte,
SurName = marx,
CombinedIncome = 82000
```

And if you press `;` for another solution:

```
?- mother_with_children_less_than_10k(Name, SurName, CombinedIncome).
Name = charlotte,
SurName = marx,
CombinedIncome = 82000 ;
Name = sarah,
SurName = chomsky,
CombinedIncome = 80000.
```

Test run for `children_earning_over_40k`

```
[debug]  ?- children_earning_over_40k(ChildrenOver40k).
ChildrenOver40k = [pat_jr, amos] .
```

Test run for `unemployed_fathers`

```
[debug]  ?- unemployed_fathers(UnemployedFathers).
UnemployedFathers = [pat] .
```

Comment: as a follow up to that - how would you write the names of children who earn over 40000 and fathers who are unemployed?

Comment: so for children_earning_over_40k , are all 3 parts of cod needed or do they show different ways of finding the list of answers.   i see the need for a list to store the children in but i get lost after that

Comment: Please put a little effort in tracing the calls  from `children_earning_over_40k` and you will see which predicates/facts are needed and which are not.  

What might be confusing for you is the `findall/3` and `flatten/2`, those predicates are built-in and you can find documentation on them by googling. Remember this is just a sample solution, there are many other ways of doing it as well, if this is an homework assignment you can use my solution as an example but you will probably understand better by trying your own solution.  Good luck!

Comment: If you have any explicit question I'm happy to answer but if the question regards general understanding of the code you are better of experimenting with the code and/or reading manuals.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tips for posting questions from assessed homeworks.

- Change the names! Yes, it sounds so obvious, but changing the names of variables, or in this case fake people, makes it a lot less obvious that you're getting answers from the internet.
- Change some values, or obscure it a little. Maybe we don't need to compare the same total income as the question?

Hope these helped, if you're still stuck, remember you are allowed to work in pairs for the assignment, so maybe ask someone else to work with you. Keep working at it, it's now pushed back to Thursday. Good luck.